# Php form ajax request not working , yii framework

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I am doing a yii web application
i have a drop down list that should be dependent on another , i use ajax however it doesnt work. 
ive seen the yii tutorial for dependent drop downs and searched everywhere.
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24
this is my main drop down list:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'sourceID'); ?>
    <?php
    echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'sourceID', CHtml::listData(Sources::model()->findAll(), 'sourceID', 'name'), array('empty' => 'select source'), array(
        'ajax' => array(
            'type' => 'POST',
            'url' => CController::createUrl('reservations/atest'),
            'update' => '#meal'
        )
            )
    );
    ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'sourceID'); ?>
</div>
```

this is the dependent drop down list :

```
<div  class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'meal'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'meal', array()); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'meal'); ?>
</div>
```

this is my controller action:

```
  public function actionAtest() {

    $data = Sources::model()->findAll();

    $data = CHtml::listData($data, 'sourceID', 'name');

    foreach ($data as $value => $name) {
        echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => $value), CHtml::encode($name),true);
    } }
```

also, i added the action to the access rules.
any help is appreciated ,
thank you in advance.

Comment: i forgot to mention that i used fire bug to debug the ajax requests but,i cant even find them. i looked in the 'console' tab under 'all'.

Comment: Did you check the resulting html?

Comment: what do u mean by resulting html? and how do i check it

Comment: Does the dropdown markup look like it should be if you look at the source code of your form?

Comment: sry, i dont understand your question, can you explain more plz?

Comment: Look at your source code of your page with this form if the form is generated as you wanted.

Comment: well , the code is generated as i want , yes. But i cant find any sign of any ajax or xmlhttp anywhere.

Comment: Any hints in the error console?

Comment: try to step through the ajax script generated by yii using fire bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You placed the `ajax` option after the `htmlOptions`. Here is the modified code

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'sourceID'); ?>
    <?php
    echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'sourceID', CHtml::listData(Sources::model()->findAll(), 'sourceID', 'name'), array('empty' => 'select source','ajax' => array(
            'type' => 'POST',
            'url' => CController::createUrl('reservations/atest'),
            'update' => '#meal'
       )
      )
    );
    ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'sourceID'); ?>
</div>
```

And instead of using forms dropdownlist use `CHtml::dropDownList` for the dependent drop-down.

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('meal','', array());
```

You can also use `CActiveForm::dropDownList` but in that case you have to use `CHtml::resolveNameId` in the `update` option of `ajax`

Comment: Thanks alot this solved it , it was indeed in the wrong array , but 2 quick questions plz , why doesnt it work with form->dropDownList ? and also ,whats the difference between CActiveForm and normal form ? i just need to understand more , if you can help . Thanks again =)

Comment: @user1438230 The `form->dropDownList` will render a dropdownlist with an `id` that is determined by the `model` and `attribute` params. So in order to work with `form->dropDownList` you should change the `'update'=>'#meal'` of `ajax` to `'update'=>'#the_generated_id'` . Youcan either replace `the_generated_id` by looking the html sourcecode rendered or use the `CHtml::resolveNameId` function. Hope it is clear